# Any help on correct syntax in Swift to access a "typedef void PaStream;" from a C file?

Tags: c++, c, swift, portaudio

I have compiled and imported a dylib C Library called portaudio ([PortAudio website](http://portaudio.com)) into an Xcode 6.1 Swift project, all the functions / types are accessible except for one which is

> typedef void PaStream;

I am having trouble understanding how to use that in Swift, in C I declare it like:

```
PaStream *audioStream = NULL;
```

Can anybody help on the Swift equivalent as I get a warning saying undeclared Type / unresolved identifier, it looks like Swift can not bridge a typedef void xyz; ?

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm not a Swift programmer, but you might look at [COpaquePointer](http://swiftdoc.org/type/COpaquePointer/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C typedef

```
typedef void PaStream;
```

is indeed not imported to Swift because you can't define a variable of type `void`.
Even in C, you would only define *pointer* variables of type `PaStream *`.

Therefore you could add

```
typedef PaStream *PaStreamPtr;
```

to the bridging header file and then use it as

```
var audioStream : PaStreamPtr = nil
```