# Using an Objective-C typedef void in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, typedef, type-alias

I am using an Objective-C API in a new Swift environment. For the most part everything is working great but I'm getting stuck on a typedef issue.

The API has a typedef defined as:

```
typedef void* TESTHANDLE;
```

Usually in Objective-C I'd simply use this like declaring any kind of variable:

```
TESTHANDLE NewTestHandle;
```

The image below is an example from an Objective-C project that uses this.

[image]

I want to declare a new TESTHANDLE variable in Swift, the same way I do above. I need to assign a value to TestHandle later in the code, which is of type TESTHANDLE.

[image]

Reading up on this over I see that typealias is now the way to go BUT I can't change the API.

How can I use this typedef from Objective-C in Swift?

Comment: I've added a bit more information. I'm not sure of the exact terminology to use to get my point across.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I'll dig some more based on that info

Comment: I found some info on bridging https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27886861/any-help-on-correct-syntax-in-swift-to-access-a-typedef-void-pastream-from-a

Comment: Writing `TESTHANDLE TestHandle` is like writing `Int i` in Swift. It's not valid syntax. The Swift syntax is `let testHandle: TESTHANDLE = ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by simply adding a bridging header to your project.

Taking example of the following Objective C class:

[image]

1. Add a header file to your project. The default naming convention is -Bridging-Header.h
2. Import your Objective-C API headers to this header using #import statement.

[image]

3. Under project Build Setting set this header as the briddge between your Objective-C and Swift world by putting the path of it in "Objective-C Bridging Header". Relative paths to your .xcodeproj will simply work.

[image]

4. Use the type in Swift as usual

[image]

However keep in mind that all such types will be treated as `UnsafeRawPointer` or `UnsafeMutableRawPointer` in Swift.

Comment: Thanks Ayan, that's the first bit of the puzzle! I have another piece now, I'll post a link here in a minute, just in case you can help me there, too!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840722/outputting-a-value-to-a-typedef-pointer-in-swift is my new query if you have time