# outputting a value to a typedef pointer in swift

Tags: ios, swift, typedef, unsafemutablepointer

I'm almost certain the title of this isn't correct but here goes...

I'm bridging to an Objective-C class to set a typedef. The bridge is set up and I'm able to declare the typedef var correctly.

In Objective-C I also called a method from the same class that, when called, output a value to the variable TestHandle.

```
var TestHandle : TESTHANDLE
TestInit(&TestHandle)
```

When I try this using Swift 5 I get this error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'inout TESTHANDLE' (aka 'inout UnsafeMutableRawPointer') to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<TESTHANDLE?>?' (aka 'Optional<UnsafeMutablePointer<Optional<UnsafeMutableRawPointer>>>')
```

Any pointers?

Comment: UpperCamelCase is reserved for type names in Swift. You should name your variables, properties and such using lowerCamelCase.

Comment: Roger that, will do so from now on

Comment: What's the documentation for this API? C's APIs are very heavily reliant on documentation (because C's type system doesn't communicate much itself, such as who's responsible for allocating and deallocating a given pointer)

Comment: You can follow the link to get it all done:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/780-unsafe-swift-using-pointers-and-interacting-with-c
More specifically does your `TestInit` function requires a `TESTHANDLE*` aka `void**`. If so, you need to declare your variable `TestHandle` as `var TestHandle: UnsafeMutablePointer<HANDLE?>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some observations:

- `TESTHANDLE` appears to be an alias for `UnsafeMutableRawPointer`
- `&testHandle` is taking a reference (a pointer to the location) of the `testHandle`, producing a value of type `inout UnsafeMutableRawPointer`
- As the error says, your `TestInit` function takes a variable of type `UnsafeMutablePointer<TESTHANDLE?>?`, a.k.a. `Optional<UnsafeMutablePointer<Optional<UnsafeMutableRawPointer>>>`

Swift has some rules about how `&` automatically bridges to the various pointer types, but to be frank, I don't understand them very well.

As far as I know, the Swift pointer types cannot represent nil (0x000...000). To do that, they need to be wrapped within an optional. So when you see the type

```
Optional<UnsafeMutablePointer<Optional<UnsafeMutableRawPointer>>>
```

It's actually two "semantic" parts:

```
Optional<UnsafeMutablePointer<    Optional<UnsafeMutableRawPointer>    >>
↳ A nullable pointer to ...       ↳ ... something that's a nullable pointer of unspecified (void) type
```

The reason you're getting your error is because `&testHandle` can only bridge your `UnsafeMutableRawPointer` to a `Optional<UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutableRawPointer>>`, but not the required `Optional<UnsafeMutablePointer<Optional<UnsafeMutableRawPointer>>>` (the difference is in that missing layer of "inner" nullability). To get around this, make your `testHandle` optional, yourself:

```
var testHandle: TESTHANDLE? // a.k.a. Optional<TESTHANDLE>, a.k.a. Optional< UnsafeMutableRawPointer>
```

Then, when you use the `&` operator, Swift will wrap your value in the required `Optional<UnsafeMutablePointer< ... >>` outter layer.

```
typealias TESTHANDLE = UnsafeMutableRawPointer

func testInit(_ p: UnsafeMutablePointer<TESTHANDLE?>?) {
    print("Success!")
}

var testHandle: TESTHANDLE? = nil
testInit(&testHandle)
```

Comment: That little ? held the pot of gold that had my fist pumping. Thank you sir for the thorough explanation and solution. Safe to say I don't understand it but I will re-read and try and do so!

Comment: @DanJamesPalmer Feel free to ask follow up questions!